# Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 when fetching location through zipcode

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, clgeocoder

I'm trying to fetch the the latitude and longitude based on the input parameters postal/city and country code. Below is my code, this works fine if enter City and country name but shows error if I enter zipcode and country code. Below is the code. (Note: Location services and app permissions are enabled)

```
func getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: String, countryCode: String) -> CLLocation? {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        var location: CLLocation?
        let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        address.postalCode = postalCityCode
        address.country = countryCode
        geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(address, preferredLocale: Locale.current) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                print("Error: placemark is nil")
                return
            }
            guard let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate else {
                print("Error: coordinate is nil")
                return
            }
            location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
            print("Found location = \(location)")
        }
        return location
    }
```

Working input: Shanghai, CN

Failing input: 200040, CN

Edit

Attached updated code as suggested in the answer but still experiencing same issue

[image]

Comment: seems to work for me, `getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: "200040", countryCode: "CN")`, I get:
     `Found location = Optional(<+35.86001980,+104.16580200>....`, although this is not `Shanghai`, it's `Yuzhong County, Lanzhou, Gansu, China`

Comment: Thats strange, not sure whats the issue. My locale is set to en_CN, which locale are you using?

Comment: you mean the location? I'm in Tokyo, Japan Standard Time, language English.

Comment: "en_JP" is my`Locale.current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are using `return location` before it is set, since `geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(...)` is an asynchronous function.

That means you need to use a completion handler (for example) to return the `location`, when it has the results, something like this:

```
func getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: String, countryCode: String, completion: @escaping ( CLLocation?) -> Void) {
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var location: CLLocation?
    let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
    address.postalCode = postalCityCode
    address.country = countryCode
    geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(address, preferredLocale: Locale.current) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
            return completion(nil)
        }
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
            print("Error: placemark is nil")
            return completion(nil)
        }
        guard let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate else {
            print("Error: coordinate is nil")
            return completion(nil)
        }
        location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        print("\n--> Found location = \(location) \n")
        completion(location)   // <-- here
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: "200040", countryCode: "CN") { location in
     print("\n---> location: \(location) \n")
 }
```

EDIT-1

for testing and isolating the issue, try this code in a new SwiftUI project:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cityLocation = CLLocation()

    var body: some View {
        Text(cityLocation.description)
            .onAppear {
                getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: "200040", countryCode: "CN") { location in
                    print("\n---> location: \(location) \n")
                    if let theLocation = location {
                        cityLocation = theLocation
                    }                    
                }
            }
    }
    
    func getLocationFrom(postalCityCode: String, countryCode: String, completion: @escaping ( CLLocation?) -> Void) {
        
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        var location: CLLocation?
        let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        address.postalCode = postalCityCode
        address.country = countryCode
        geocoder.geocodePostalAddress(address, preferredLocale: Locale.current) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error: \(error!)")
                return completion(nil)
            }
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                print("Error: placemark is nil")
                return completion(nil)
            }
            guard let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate else {
                print("Error: coordinate is nil")
                return completion(nil)
            }
            location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
            print("\n--> Found location = \(location) \n")
            completion(location)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting location value as nil. I created a new project and copy pasted this code on viewcontroller, set custom location on simulator to (+31.2203102,+121.4623931) still no luck. It works if I change the value 200040 to Shanghai or any other city.

Comment: updated my answer with a fully functional code (although it is for SwiftUI), to try to isolate the issue you are having. The code as shown works well for me.

Comment: I tried this but still same, I've attached a GIF of the issue, it shows 0 for the CN zipcode but work for City and other country zipcodes. I'm on Xcode 14.1, not sure why its not working for me.

Comment: could you try my code on a real device, ios or mac, not Preview, `Preview` is not a simulator, it is just a look-alike thing.

Comment: Yes, I already tried on device as well but still same issue. Seems like only for CN zipcodes its throwing error, city is fine. Not sure why its working for you and not for me. Whats your OS version?

Comment: Ok, I'm on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. Maybe it is different on older systems. Cannot think what else could account for your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll update my Xcode to 14.2 and check.

Comment: It started working when I put in the country name instead of country code. Thanks for the support.

Comment: good to hear you got your issue resolved.